# How to browse a file using FileDialog

Tags: vb.net, filepath, openfiledialog

I want to Browse a File on button click
And get file path in a text box.

Here is what I have tried   :

```
FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
TextBox66.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
```

This is not working. Any suggesions ?

Comment: What is the type of the 'dialog' object?

Comment: Why do you just need a path? I am assuming you will need to upload the contents of the selected file too, right?

Comment: Uhm..lopenfiledialog to the rescue?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I want to get path for database connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles        Button1.Click
    Dim oFileDlg As New OpenFileDialog
    oFileDlg.ShowDialog()
    textbox1.text = oFileDlg.FileName
End Sub
```